# Whatsapp Cloud API using our own number for send message

Tags: facebook, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I have registered 2 numbers and it's connected. The problem is, I wanted to use our own number not a test number on this API Call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{{Version}}/{{Phone-Number-ID}}/messages

{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "to": "{{Recipient-Phone-Number}}",
    "type": "template",
    "template": {
        "name": "hello_world",
        "language": {
            "code": "en_US"
        }
    }
}
```

I have successfully sent the message by the test number. My question is how to use our own number?

From the app dashboard, I have checked the production number is zero but on the WhatsApp business manager I have 3 numbers, 1 for testing and 2 is should be act as the production number. I have 2 waba ID and pretty sure I use the correct one.

When trying to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{{Version}}/{{WABA-ID}}/phone_numbers

{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '*****' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 33,
        "fbtrace_id": "Ac5S6tqiApK**l1Y_t4nv"
    }
}
```

Does it require BSP to use my Own Number? How to get the phone-number-id?

Ps. My 2 other numbers are already connected with messagebird and it can send messages successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your phone number from your developer app settings, under WhatsApp > API Setup > Step 5 > "Step 5: Add a phone number" where you will see the "Add phone number" button, as you can see in the screenshot,

[image]

After successfully adding a phone number you can see the phone number ID and WhatsApp Business Account ID, as you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I have registered the number on business.facebook.com and have a different WABA ID. Is it wrong?

Comment: I think I have added a number, but somehow it makes different WABA ID and not connected to the Meta Developer Dashboard. Anything Wrong?